# AppleScript clipboard race condition

Tags: applescript, clipboard, race-condition

I want to use AppleScript to paste some text into the current application while preserving the preexisting contents of the clipboard.

```
on writeFromClipboard(someText)
    set oldClipboard to the clipboard
    log oldClipboard
    set the clipboard to someText
    log (the clipboard)
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "v" using {command down}
    end tell
    log (the clipboard)
    set the clipboard to oldClipboard
end writeFromClipboard

writeFromClipboard("new text")
```

When I have `old text` on the clipboard when this script is run, I get the following event log and `old text` is pasted. I can only conclude that the text is actually pasted after the clipboard contents have been changed back.

```
tell application "AppleScript Editor"
    the clipboard
        --> "old text"
end tell
(*old text*)
tell application "AppleScript Editor"
    set the clipboard to "new text"
    the clipboard
        --> "new text"
end tell
(*new text*)
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "v" using {command down}
end tell
tell application "AppleScript Editor"
    the clipboard
        --> "new text"
end tell
(*new text*)
tell application "AppleScript Editor"
    set the clipboard to "old text"
end tell
```

Short of adding a pause after the paste keystroke, is there a way to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Standard Additions Dictionary says:

[set the clipboard to v : Place data on an application’s clipboard. Use inside a ‘tell’ block and activate the application first.](http://applescript.wikia.com/wiki/Set_the_Clipboard_to) (Link to AppleScript Wiki)

Try it this way:

```
on writeFromClipboard(someText)
    tell application "TextEdit"
        activate
        set oldClipboard to the clipboard
        set the clipboard to someText
        --delay 0.2
        tell application "System Events" to tell process "TextEdit"
            keystroke "v" using {command down}
        end tell
        set the clipboard to oldClipboard
    end tell
end writeFromClipboard

writeFromClipboard("new text")
```

For safety, I would still add a little delay.

Comment: I've ended up using `pbcopy` and `pbpaste` to preserve the clipboard and only using Applescript for the paste keystroke.